# How can i handle the date when the input is NULL

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, null

If I give the input as `06/2007` then it works fine.

Giving `2007/06` shows invalid input -- fine

`NULL` 'nothing' means it has give mandatory input. But it is giving invalid input which is wrong. How can I handle these two conditions?

```
PROCEDURE validateDate(v_InputDate IN VARCHAR2) is

  ErrorMSG  VARCHAR2(1000);
  v_tmpDate varchar2(20);
  g_dateInvalid EXCEPTION;
  g_dateError EXCEPTION;
  g_ErrorCode NUMBER;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('Input date is' || v_InputDate);
  BEGIN
    IF v_InputDate IS NULL THEN
      RAISE g_dateError;
    ELSIF v_InputDate IS NOT NULL THEN
      v_tmpDate := to_date(v_InputDate,
                           'MM/YYYY');
      dbms_output.put_line('Converted date is' || v_tmpDate);
    END IF;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RAISE g_dateInvalid;
  END;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN g_dateError THEN
    g_ErrorCode := -20002;
    ErrorMSG    := 'Mandatory input cannot be null. Enter a valid date in MMYYYY fromat';
    raise_application_error(g_ErrorCode,
                            ErrorMSG);

  WHEN g_dateInvalid THEN
    g_ErrorCode := -20001;
    ErrorMSG    := 'Invalid DATE should be in MMYYYY format. Please verify. ';
    raise_application_error(g_ErrorCode,
                            ErrorMSG);

END validateDate;
```

Comment: Please guys..please help me out..its urgent..

Comment: Explain what you need.. not very clear from your question.. write down whats happening for given input and what result is expected.. where you are facing problem

Comment: Your exception logic is somewhat strange - why do you raise an g_dateError, capture it and throw a g_dateInvalid exception? This means your outer exception block for g_dateError can never be reached.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt And that's exactly the reason why OP don't get the results he is expecting when `v_inputdate is null`.

Comment: I need to throw two different types of exceptions when the input date is null saying that "Mandatory input date should be given" and the other one when the user has given the wrong input saying him "Invalid input pls give the correct input"..

Comment: Then don't catch the g_dateError in the inner exception handler, or re-raise it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way you are doing it at the moment is a little more complicated than it actually needs to be. There was no need to nest another block. I have tested the following and it works fine for me:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE validateDate(
   v_InputDate IN VARCHAR2
)
IS
   v_tmpDate varchar2(20);
   g_dateError EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
   dbms_output.put_line('Input date is' || v_InputDate);

   IF v_InputDate IS NULL THEN
       RAISE g_dateError;
   ELSE
       v_tmpDate := to_date(v_InputDate, 'MM/YYYY');
       dbms_output.put_line('Converted date is' || v_tmpDate);
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN g_dateError THEN
       raise_application_error(-20002, 'Mandatory input cannot be null. Enter a valid date in MMYYYY fromat');
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
       raise_application_error(-20001, 'Invalid DATE should be in MMYYYY format. Please verify. ');
END validateDate;
 /
```

Tested with null and got error -20002, tested with 'text' and got -20001.